# apexcharts Radial Charts font size

Tags: apexcharts

Im using **[apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/radialbar-charts/basic/)** to my website, I  have some conflict , anyone know how to change font size of
value and labels put the bottom and value put the center

**code here**

**JavaScript**

```
var options = {
          series: [70],
          chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: 'radialBar',
        },
        plotOptions: {
          radialBar: {
            hollow: {
              size: '70%',
            }
          },
        },
        labels: ['Cricket'],
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do refer the [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/radialbar/) for formatting the data labels and their corresponding values. Following properties can be overridden in your chart `options` to set the font size and positioning.

```
plotOptions: {
  ...
  dataLabels: {
    name: {  // label name, eg: "Cricket"
     ...
     fontSize: '<font size in px>' // default: 16px; change to preferred size
     offsetY: <position offset from top> // +ve for downward, -ve for upward direction> // default: -10; change to >120 to push the label down
    },

    value: {  // label value, eg: "70%"
      ...
      fontSize: '<font size in px>' // default: 14px; change to required size
      offsetY: <position offset from top> // default: +16; set to 0 to center the value
    }

  }
}
```

Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/deepakdevanand/pen/MWjwOey) with above settings modified to set the label at bottom of the plot, and value centered.